# Why axios with async/await not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I wanna change `DoorState` when click button.

After post API to change `DoorState`, call get API to check robot state.

Actually `DoorState` is changed.
But not change in `console.log(after)` code. Why?

```
{
    deliveryPost.Delivery.status === 'assigned' &&
        (checkDoorState(deliveryPost.Delivery.postId) === 'closed' ? ( <
            >
            <
            button className = "bg-white text-teal-500 py-2 px-4 ml-2 border border-teal-500 rounded hover:bg-teal-500 hover:text-white"
            onClick = {
                () => clickRobotAction(deliveryPost.Delivery.postId, 'open')
            } >
            Open Door <
            /button> <
            />
        ) : ( <
            >
            <
            button className = "bg-white text-teal-500 py-2 px-4 ml-2 border border-teal-500 rounded hover:bg-teal-500 hover:text-white"
            onClick = {
                () => clickRobotAction(deliveryPost.Delivery.postId, 'close')
            } >
            Close Door <
            /button> <
            />
        ))
}
``
`

`
``
const clickRobotAction = async (postId: string, action: string) => {
    const appliedRobot = robots.find(robot => robot.postId === postId);
    const {
        robotId
    } = appliedRobot;

    try {
        await axios.post(`api/${robotId}/action/${action}`); // DoorState open <=> close
        const after = await axios.get('api/robots');

        console.log(after); // But not change in this log. Why?
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Your code seems right. Are you sure the problem is not in the Backend? May you post it too? Edit: Maybe you should post `api/robots/${robotId}/actions/...`?

Comment: Shouldn't `after` be assigned a specific robot id (maybe also its state) in `const after = await axios.get('api/robots');`? Does a call to `api/robots` return the door state??

Comment: Yes. api/robots has door state in response.

Comment: I think that api/robots is not sync. If I write setTImeout(() => console.log(after), 1000}, It works.

Comment: axios.get() is async, it returns a Promise. try...catch is synchronous. Maybe when you `post` to change the DoorState, your backend needs to do a process (database, hardware stuff, ...) which takes longer than the time you are calling the `get`.

Comment: OK, I get the answer why it doesn't works. The BE team said that they made the api considering the time required to open the robot's door. :(

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think it is because the axios.post request should be axios.get since you aren't adding a second overload parameter for an object.  Since you are just sending a query string then I think it should just be a get request not certain though I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly this api's call is correct. Actually doorState is change. But that console is not apply.